# How to get specific co-ordinate along Chartjs donut arc

Tags: javascript, math, chart.js, donut-chart

I need to find the specific x and y coordinates of each arc. Below is a photo illustrating exactly which coordinates I require, color-coded according to each arc. I need those two points of x and y coordinates for every arc element.

[image]

Here is a sample arc object(from my own project):

[image]

Below is some sample code for this:

```
const data = {
        labels: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
        datasets: [{
          label: 'Weekly Sales',
          data: [18, 12, 6, 9, 12, 3, 9],
          backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 26, 104, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
            'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)'
          ],
          borderColor: [
            'rgba(255, 26, 104, 1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
            'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)'
          ],
          borderWidth: 1,
          cutout: '70%'
        }]
      };

      const donutArc = {
        id: 'donutArc',
        afterDraw: (chart) => {
          const { ctx, data: { datasets }, } = chart;
          
          datasets.forEach((dataset, i) =>{
            chart.getDatasetMeta(i).data.forEach((arc, j) => {
                console.log(arc)
            })
          })

        }
      }

      // config 
      const config = {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data,
        options: {
          plugins: {
            legend: {
              display: false
            }
          }
        },
        plugins: [donutArc]
      };

      // render init block
      const myChart = new Chart(
        document.getElementById('myChart'),
        config
      );
```

Full code can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/tpLrxb53/.

I'm pretty sure this involves dealing with the `startAngle` and `endAngle`, but I am unable to make sense of them in the documentation here: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/api/classes/ArcElement.html

Any explanation/solutions will be highly appreciated

Comment: Think of it in units. You have the center. That's one thing. Be able to display points on the picture. You have the angle. You have the distance. Try to move a point from the center at an angle and distance. Print resulting point out on that screen. See if it's correct. Never deal with the whole problem at once. Always just thinking about tiny parts of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get points on a circle with the formula

x = radius*sin(angle), y = radius*cos(angle)

So I suppose in your code you could do something like

```js
const donutArc = {
    id: 'donutArc',
    afterDraw: (chart) => {
    const { ctx, data: { datasets }, } = chart;     
    datasets.forEach((dataset, i) =>{
        chart.getDatasetMeta(i).data.forEach((arc, j) => {
            r1 = arc.innerRadius
            r2 = arc.outerRadius
            xinner = r1*Math.sin(arc.startAngle)
            yinner = r1*Math.cos(arc.startAngle)
            xouter = r2*Math.sin(arc.startAngle)
            youter = r2*Math.cos(arc.startAngle)
            // then I guess here you would draw something
            })
        })
    }
}
```

This is assuming the origin of the graph is (0,0) and that`startAngle`, `outerRadius` and `innerRadius` are what they would appear to be